# FilesMatch results in Internal Server Error

Tags: .htaccess, caching, error-handling

I added the code below to my **.htaccess** file to enable caching files for 3 days. After that my website wasn't available anymore and I got a message displayed that told me it's an **Internal Server Error**

*The code:*

```
 # 3 DAYS 
    <FilesMatch "\.(html|css|js|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|ico|swf)$"> Header set Cache-Control "max-age=259200, proxy-revalidate" </FilesMatch>
```

*The message:*

> Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal
>   error or misconfiguration and was
>   unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server
>   administrator, webmaster@exampple.com
>   and inform them of the time the error
>   occurred, and anything you might have
>   done that may have caused the error.
>
> More information about this error may
>   be available in the server error log.

What is wrong with the FilesMatch or what else could cause the Internal Server Error? 
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It has to be on **multiple lines**, not all in a single line. This one works fine for me:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(html|css|js|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|ico|swf)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=259200, proxy-revalidate"
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: It's working! Thank you. BTW: Is it recommended to put the <FilesMatch at the top or bottom in the .htaccess file?

Comment: I always put it on a top -- I never thought about this on purpose.

Comment: Before I knew about the .htaccess I used this in my .html sites meta settings: `<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="cache"/>
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="cache"/>` Should I remove it now or leave it as is?

Comment: I would say "yes - remove" (since you already have headers explicitly set by Apache) .. but I cannot guarantee 100%, sorry

Comment: Sounds logical. One last short questions: Does the FilesMatch in my servers root .htaccess file affect also subdomains or do they need a seperate one? (Sorry, I'm very hungry for informations today...)

Comment: If that folder is part of subdomain, then yes. But if subdomain is located in subfolder of the root and .htaccess is in the root folder (which makes it outside of subdomain), then No.

Answer (score 18):

I had this issue a while ago, You can solve it by typing
"sudo a2enmod headers" in the command line

Comment: That was the perfect answer for my issue, Thanks @thomas

Comment: After that, you need to run ``service apache2 restart`` but Apache will tell you about this anyway after you enable the headers mod.

Comment: This is what I needed to know. I kept get 500 Internal error. Once I enabled the headers, my htaccess update worked like a charm.

Answer (score 9):

this is another solution
http://diogomelo.net/node/24

To enable this module, log in as root, and create a symbolic link from mods-available/headers.load to mods-enabled. After that, reload apache and it's done. To do so, I've used this commands.

```
su -
cd /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/
ln -s ../mods-available/headers.load headers.load
sh /etc/init.d/apache2 force-reload
```

After that procedure the issue is solved.

Comment: Thank you! Here is the one line version `sudo ln -s /etc/apache2/mods-available/headers.load /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/headers.load`

Answer (score 0):

This is another possible solution, after applying multiple lines do this simple possible solution.

Problem:

You may have copied and pasted the htaccess instructions directly from a sample code on a website or a slide presentation or somewhere else which creates a problem with the **text encoding format**.

Solution:

Copy the code again but this time paste it on a simple notepad or text editor and then, copy and paste it again into the ataccess file. This will remove any encoding problem.

Answer (score 0):

Another problem you can have which returns error 500 it's you don't have enabled the `AllowOverride` directive correctly on the Apache conf file.

Example:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName yoursitename
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/site
        <Directory /var/www/html/site>
                Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
                Require all granted
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error_site.log
```

On that sample there's one `AllowOverride none` which blocks all .htaccess modifications you can do.

You can remove that `AllowOverride None` or modify it allowing only the directives do you need. On the example you placed with `AllowOverride FileInfo` will be ok.

More info about the AllowOverride directive here: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/es/mod/core.html#allowoverride